# OnPropertyChanged doesn't update UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, listbox

The window contains a ListBox and a TextBlock, and my intention is to update the TextBlock when the selection changes in the ListBox.

I have this class:

```
class ViewModelMain : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<MemEntity> items { get; set; }
    public object SelectedItem 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = SelectedItem;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public object _selectedItem { get; set; }

    public ViewModelMain()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<MemEntity> {
        new MemEntity{s = "a", Correct = 2, Incorrect = 1},
        new MemEntity{s = "b"},
        new MemEntity{s = "c"}
        };
    }
}
```

This is ViewModelBase:

```
class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The View:

```
<ListBox x:Name="items" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding items}" DisplayMemberPath="s"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.s}"/>
```

I thought I had everything in box now, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `_selectedItem = SelectedItem;` does nothing. You have a setter which doesn't use `value`. Make  `_selectedItem = value;`

Comment: Try to set the mode of binding to two-way for selectedItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_selectedItem = SelectedItem;` does nothing. You have a setter which doesn't use `value`. Make `_selectedItem = value;`

use the standard snippet to create a property with a backing private field (with concreate type):

```
private MemEntity _selectedItem;
public MemEntity SelectedItem 
{ 
    get
    {
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! How incredible close I was. Kind of embarrassing mistake to do, but thanks for sorting it out.

Comment: @Pelle this is basically an exact dupe of what I showed you in the answer provided to your previous question.

Comment: @Nkosi, I actually opened the previous Q but didn't scroll to the 2nd answer. Pity because it is a duplicate answer indeed.

Comment: @ASh not an issue. I did find it weird that the OP basically asked the same question again when the accepted answer was already provided previously. Not your fault. I still up-voted your answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. Basically thought I'd done something else wrong, which was unrelated, but I just screwed up that one line. Didn't mean to cause hassle. Again, sorry.